# Transform all pixels from one projection to another projection under the Matplotlib Basemap

Tags: matplotlib, basemap

Is there a way to transform all pixels from one projection to another projection under the Matplotlib Basemap?

Comment: You can delete this question if you no longer want in online. That is better than vandalizing the question & Answer.

Comment: I don't want to get into a Rollback war, so I'll suggest another solution. The Mods can dissociate this Question from the OP's Account. I've seen it being done on Stackoverflow. That might be useful, if the OP no longer wants this Question. I'll be sad if the question is deleted, because it has such a well written detailed answer.

Comment: @Devdatta Thank you for the suggestion.  I have taken care of it.

Answer (score 5):

Matplotlib Basemap has the ability to transform between coordinate systems.  Have a look **[here](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/mapcoords.html)**.  That page says:

> In order to plot data on a map, the coordinates of the data must be given in map projection coordinates. Calling a Basemap class instance with the arguments lon, lat will convert lon/lat (in degrees) to x/y map projection coordinates (in meters). The inverse transformation is done if the optional keyword inverse is set to True.

The documentation for the **[basemap module](http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html)** lists all of the projections which are supported.

For most map projections, the map projection region can either be specified by setting these keywords:

> **Keyword/Description**
>
> ```
> llcrnrlon - longitude of lower left hand corner of the desired map domain (degrees).
> llcrnrlat - latitude of lower left hand corner of the desired map domain (degrees).
> urcrnrlon - longitude of upper right hand corner of the desired map domain (degrees).
> urcrnrlat -latitude of upper right hand corner of the desired map domain (degrees).
> ```

or these

> **Keyword/Description**
>
> ```
> width -width of desired map domain in projection coordinates (meters).
> height - height of desired map domain in projection coordinates (meters).
> lon_0 - center of desired map domain (in degrees).
> lat_0 - center of desired map domain (in degrees).
> ```

Comment: Suggested addendum/conclusion:

So to transform from projection A to projection B, first inverse transform from map projection A coordinates (meters) into geographic space (degrees), then (forward) transform from geographic space (degrees) to map projection B coordinates (meters).